# Is there a SharePoint Searching Tool?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search, wiki, enterprise-wiki

If possible, I am looking to add a Search Field on my Team Site on the Wiki Page.

[image]

If possible, I would like the Search box to go in next to the title (Where the read box is located).
I'm not sure if SharePoint does provide this feature, so any comments/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure is. There is a webpart called Search Box, that searches on whatever scope or filter you want. You can ideally have that Search filtered to a specific section, site, scope, or keyword, etc. and have a different landing page.

Also if you are using a Listviewwebpart, in the Advanced settings of the webpart, you have a setting called "Display Search Box" that will act as a search box for the listview items.